# How can I get an HTML tag’s value to send an HTML.Action()

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-mvc, razor, html.actionlink

I have these lines of code:

```
<span 
  class="close-modal"
  onclick="@Html.Action("SaveNotes", "CallCenter", new { activityId = item.callIdKey, noteText = "test1" })">
  &times;
</span>
&nbsp;
Notes: <br />
<textarea name="paragraph_text" rows="5" style="width:90%">
  @item.NoteText 
</textarea>
```

I would like to replace `test1` from the `noteText` route variable and instead change it to whatever the value in the `<textarea>` tag is.

Is there an elegant way of doing this without writing a giant block of jQuery code?

Comment: The only way to modify your DOM (HTML) after it has been delivered to the client is with JavaScript.

Comment: Can you clarify 'whatever the value in between the tags' is? In this example, do you mean &times; or @item.NoteText ?

Comment: @HBlackorby The <textarea> </textarea> tags let users type in any input. It's a box that has user made notes in it. I want to save that to the server when they close the modal.

Comment: So you either post a form or post with jquery and ajax, take your pick

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A @gunr2171 notes in the comments, the only way to dynamically update a link once it's been rendered to the browser is via some form of client-side scripting, typically JavaScript. In your case, I'd recommend doing something like this:

```
<span 
  class="close-modal" 
  data-href-template="@Url.Action("SaveNotes", "CallCenter", new {activityId = item.callIdKey, noteText="{note}"})"
  >
  &times;
</span>
```

> *Note:* As @HBlackorby notes in his answer, you shouldn't be using `@Html.Action()` here; I assume you meant `@Url.Action()`.

This way, your JavaScript has a template (`data-href-template`) that it can work against with a clearly defined token (`{note}`) to replace, instead of needing to parse the URL in order to identify where the previously replaced text is. Otherwise, you potentially end up in a scenario where you type e.g. `CallCenter` into your `<textarea />` and it's now an ambiguous reference that you can't just blindly replace. Or, worse, you type 'a' and it's *really* ambiguous.

If you *are* already using **jQuery** on your site, the actual replacement might be done using something along the lines of:

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
  $('span.close-modal').click(function() {
    var noteInput    = $('textarea[name="paragraph_text"]');
    var encodedNote  = encodeURI(noteInput.text());
    var template     = $(this).data("href-template");
    var targetUrl    = template.replace("{note}", encodedNote);
    window.location.href = targetUrl;
  });
});
```

You can also do this without jQuery, obviously—and should if you're not already depending on it. The point is to illustrate that this doesn't necessarily need to be a "giant block of jQuery code". In fact, this could be done in just a few lines—and probably should be. I deliberately broke it out into multiple steps and variables for the sake of readability.

Comment: Since you are going jquery, it may be best to accompany the answer with an ajax post. He is trying to post data (He mentioned this in the comments) using a get request. As it's quite clear this is no form submission. Also, all of this can happen once with jquery `onclick` as opposed to a jquery `change` event on the `textarea`.

Comment: @AbdulG: Oh, good suggestion on only doing the replacement reactively `onclick` as opposed to preemptively for each change! I've updated my code to reflect that.

Comment: @AbdulG: As far as whether this is submitted as a `POST` or a `GET`, I can't find anywhere that the OP suggests that's a requirement. In the comments, they only mention that they want to "save that to the server".

Comment: fair enough, for some reason I always try to approach problems in an attempt to provide a 'turn-key solution'

Answer (score 2):

`@Html.Action()` renders a partial view as an HTML string during page processing (on the server side). It doesn't exist any more in the markup, once the page is sent to the browser. You can't do what you are trying to do this way. At the very least, I'm sure you don't want to render a partial view inside the `onclick` event of your `<span>` tag.

Why not instead use an HTML helper for the `<textarea>` tag? Then you can get whatever value the user typed into it on the server code. You'll want to make the form post itself back to the server on the `close-modal` element:

```
<span class="close-modal" onclick="$('form').submit()">&times;</span>&nbsp;
<form method="post" action="@Url.Action("SaveNotes", "CallCenter", new { activityId=item.callIdKey }">
  Notes: <br />
  @Html.TextArea("noteText", item.NoteText, new { rows="5", style="width:90%" }) 
</form>
```

This assumes you have **jQuery** already (a common assumption with ASP.NET). You may not need the `<form>` tags if you already have a form on your page.

Comment: This is a good alternative. There are a couple of minor tweeks needed, though. First, the `TextArea`'s name should be `noteText` not `paragraph_text` since it's intended to target the `noteText` parameter on the target action. Second, the `form` needs to have the action set to the base `@Url.Action()`, assuming that the link is referencing a different action on a different controller. I've proposed an edit with these modifications.